# React Native Modal Error on Expo 48 Update

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-modal

I'm currently building an app using React Native and Expo. It is right at the end of prod but was running on an old version of Expo. With the new Expo SDK 48 release my version was about to be depracated so I decided to update the Expo version.

Everything seemed to be fine post-upgrade, however, now there is something strange going on with my modals. One seems to be operational, another returns an error on open, and another returns the same ambiguous error on close. All of these modals were completely functional before the upgrade and the error message doesn't seem etremely helpful to me. Everytime the error appears, it duplicates 6 times, labelling the source of the error in each of the modals. This is the error below for one of the modals, the other errors look very similar, just located in the other modals.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function

This error is located at:
    in ReactNativeModal (created by CreatePodModal)
    in CreatePodModal (created by Content)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by withAnimatable(View))
    in withAnimatable(View) (created by Content)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Content)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Content)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Content)
    in Content (created by HomeScreen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by HomeScreen)
    in HomeScreen (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by HomeStackScreen)
    in HomeStackScreen (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Screen)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by BottomTabView)
    in RNSScreenNavigationContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by BottomTabView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by BottomTabView)
    in BottomTabView (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by BottomTabNavigator)
    in BottomTabNavigator (created by Tabs)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Tabs)
    in Tabs (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by DebugContainer)
    in DebugContainer (created by MaybeNestedStack)
    in MaybeNestedStack (created by SceneView)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SceneView)
    in RNSScreen (created by AnimatedComponent)
    in AnimatedComponent
    in AnimatedComponentWrapper (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by ScreenStack)
    in RNSScreenStack (created by ScreenStack)
    in ScreenStack (created by NativeStackViewInner)
    in NativeStackViewInner (created by NativeStackView)
    in RNCSafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaProvider)
    in SafeAreaProvider (created by SafeAreaInsetsContext)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by NativeStackView)
    in NativeStackView (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by NativeStackNavigator)
    in NativeStackNavigator (created by NavigationStack)
    in ImageGalleryProvider (created by OverlayProvider)
    in AttachmentPickerProvider (created by OverlayProvider)
    in MessageOverlayProvider (created by OverlayProvider)
    in TranslationProvider (created by OverlayProvider)
    in OverlayProvider (created by NavigationStack)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by NavigationStack)
    in NavigationStack (created by App)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator
    in BaseNavigationContainer
    in ThemeProvider
    in NavigationContainerInner (created by App)
    in ApolloProvider (created by App)
    in AppProvider (created by App)
    in App (created by withDevTools(App))
    in withDevTools(App)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
```

Another thing to note is that I'm using the imported modal from "react-native-modal", however even after switching to the regular one from React Native itself, the errors are still occurring.

Please help, I'm so close to release and really was hoping for the upgrade to go smoothly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was being created because of a peer dependency issue. Just went through react-native-modal's package.json and made sure that all of my dependencies matched up. One was out of date and I had to manually update it in my own package.json, then run npm i. The error now no longer shows up!.